# Process vi yank buffer with python

Tags: python, vim

I would like to add a key map to VI. The idea is to yank text and pass it to a python code. 
Subsequently this python code can be used to preform some manipulations on the yanked text contained in the buffer `@"`

To do so, I added the following line to `.vimrc`

```
:map <F2> :echo system("python /tmp/t.py ".shellescape(@")) <Enter>
```

By pressing F2 the python script would run the code with `@"` as input. The problem is, that the yanked buffer contains the end line `\` is a column is yanked with `<C-r>V`.
The buffer looks like this for a column input

```
1.233\
1.111\
1.222
```

I would like to accomplish the following

1) Don't include `\` in the yank buffer is possible

2) make the pyhon script globally visible from within VI. Right now, it has to be in the same folder as the VI file, or an absolute path is needed

The latter one can be properly done by placing the script in the python site packages and importing it, but I guess, that more knowledgeble people might have better ideas. I remember seeing this done, by putting the python script in a special Vi folder.

the python code:

```
import sys   

def to_float(v):
   if len(v)>0 and v != "":
      try:
         return float(v)
      except ValueError:
          #print('yanked wrong text 1 "%s" '%v)
          try:
             return float(v[:-1])
          except ValueError:
             #print('yanked wrong text 2 "%s" '%v)
             return 0.
   else :
       return 0.      

def func(v):
  s=0.
  for i in v[1].split():  
    #print('from py >> %s <<'%i) 
    s=s+to_float(i)     
  print(">>>Summ: %17.8E"%s)   

func(sys.argv)
```

Comment: It would be easier to just write a Python function in your Vim, no? Do you need this to be in an external Python file?

Comment: if your output string is exactly the one you pasted (including newlines and the trailing '\') then all you'd need to do to get rid of the unwanted chars is to replace them with an empty string. If you want to get them on separate lines, you can just splitlines() your output and then get rid of the '\' . Something like this `my_output.replace('\n', '').replace('\\', '')` would give you a single string and `[_.replace('\\', '') for _ in my_output.splitlines()]` will give you a list of elements from each line without the '\'

Comment: If you want to cast the resulting string(s) to float, all you'd have to do is wrap each one in a try block and return the result. `for _ in [_.replace('\\', '') for _ in my_output.splitlines()]: try: float_val = float(_) except ValueError: raise **your parsing code goes here**`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python-inside-Vim (as long as it is properly set up). Just dump this into your `.vimrc` (and make sure you don't add any indent to anything between `python` and `EOF`):

```
python << EOF
import vim
def float_or_0(value):
    try:
        return float(value)
    except:
        return 0.0
def sum_column():
    lines = vim.eval('@"').splitlines()
    total = sum(float_or_0(x) for x in lines)
    print(">>>Summ: %17.8E" % total) 
EOF
xmap <F2> y:py sum_column()<Enter>
```

Select your column, and hit F2. Magic. No hassle with transfering text through shell command line.

Or, you could select one of the strategies from [Quickly calculate the total of a column of numbers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4695/quickly-calculate-the-total-of-a-column-of-numbers).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The above code works, just one has to be careful  not to insert empty lines in `.vimrc`. Could please explain the meaning of `xmap <F2> y:py`. How exactly do you manage to call python function with this bypassing the system call? Btw. this works also with just `map`

Comment: `y` yanks the selection; `:py` (abbreviated from `:python`) evaluates Python code. In this case, it calls the previously-defined Python function `sum_column`. See `:help :python`.

Comment: Is it possible to tell vim which version of python to use. For instance, I am loading python3.6 with a redhat module, but vim looks always to the python from `/usr/bin/python`. Using `map <F12> y:python3 sum_vals()<Enter>` won't work.

Comment: @AlexanderCska Vim uses up to one Python 2 and one Python 3 interpreter that it was compiled with. To change which interpreter `:python` and `:python3` invoke, you have to recompile Vim.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Actually, things used to work in the past. I guess no python3 is supported, because `:version` gives `-python3 `. I am really confused, since I checked the path with `:python import sys; print sys.executable`, which leads to a python exe with access to matplotlb. But surprise, vim says matplotlib can't be found !